# Cannot get Firefox Extension to work on loading Youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox-addon

I've started working on a Firefox extension that will hide the comment section using this simple setup

const element = document.getElementById("comments");
element.setAttribute("style", "visibility:hidden");

My problem is that it only seems to work when I go into about:debugger and manually reload it.  I'm thinking I need to format this so it activates once the comments tag has loaded in.

Have already tried implementing windows.addEventListener("load... and didn't seem to work.

Comment: You can do that using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver). Monitor the `<body>` and check when the element with ID `comments` is added.

Comment: You can also inject this CSS: `#comments { visibility:hidden; }` into the page instead of injecting JavaScript.